# Workflow REST query is using old data

Tags: list, workflow, rest, designer

I have Designer 2013 workflow that is looping through a list querying for data with REST. A condition is set where if one field is greater than today's date, and a count field as set to 1, an email is sent. It pauses for 1 day and runs in the morning. today it sent two emails for two of the rows where all the necessary fields are empty. How could this happen? Is it using cached data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you retrieve data from a list it should be current. But any variables you set internally are persisted when a workflow is dehydrated. These wont be updated the next time the workflow runs, but are just loaded from the XML the workflow is written into.

So for the exact answer we would need to see the workflow in detail, but I hope this hint helps

Comment: So, based on your suggestion, if I reset the variables at the beginning of the loop all should be well?

Comment: Like I said, you need to remember that the variables are persisted... If you only fill them at start they wont be updated. This can be desired or not, depending how you build your workflow.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. the workflow ends and the last stage has it go to the loop where the primary get hasn't happened, So it is using results from when the workflow was originally run. I changed it to go to the  top of the workflow